# Struggling to get MaterialUI 5 checkbox to work with Formik 2

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik

I'm having trouble getting Formik 5 and MUI 5 checkboxes to work together. In the Codesandbox below, you'll see a form with two unchecked checkboxes: "with MUI" and "without MUI".

The "without MUI" checkbox behaves as expected: I can check and uncheck it, and if I submit, I see `withoutMui` in the console with a value of `true` or `false`.

However, the "With MUI" checkbox exhibits different behavior. Rather than setting `true` or `false`, it creates an array of data. I get that this is done to handle multiple checkboxes grouped together. However, what I don't see is anywhere I can transform that array value into `true` or `false` before handing it off to the MUI checkbox. it looks like Typescript expects `field.checked` that comes back from `useField` to be a boolean rather than an array, so I'm not able to do any manipulation on that value without getting a Typescript error.

Interestingly, if I check the "with MUI" checkbox once, I see an array with 1 value (`on`). If I click the checkbox again, then I get an array with no values in it, but the checkbox UI does not update. So it looks like the checkbox data is getting properly updated, but the MUI checkbox can't deal with array data.

I feel like I'm doing something stupid here, and would appreciate being shown the error of my ways.

Thanks in advance!

https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-https-bb7up6

non-MUI Checkbox code from sandbox:

```
import { useField } from "formik";

const CheckboxWithoutMUI = ({ label, ...rest }) => {
  const [field, meta] = useField({ ...rest, type: "checkbox" });
  return (
    <div>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" {...field} {...rest} />
        {label}
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CheckboxWithoutMUI;
```

MUI Checkbox code from sandbox:

```
import { useField } from "formik";
import FormControlLabel from "@mui/material/FormControlLabel";
import Checkbox from "@mui/material/Checkbox";

interface IProps {
  label: string;
  name: string;
}

const CheckboxField = ({ label, ...rest }: IProps) => {
  const [field, meta] = useField({ ...rest, type: "checkbox" });

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControlLabel
        label={label}
        control={
          <Checkbox
            checked={field.checked}
            onChange={field.onChange}
            id={field.name}
          />
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default CheckboxField;
```

| Software | Version(s) |
| --- | --- |
| Formik | 2.2.9 |
| React | 17.0.2 |
| TypeScript | 4.5.5 |
| Browser | Chrome (Mac) 101.0.4951.64 |
| npm/Yarn | 8.5.0 |
| Operating System | macOS 12.4 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference in behavior between the two checkboxes is due to not giving the MUI checkbox a `value`. This causes Formik to manage the checkbox value differently.

If you remove the `value` prop from the non-MUI checkbox, it will behave the same as the MUI checkbox in your sandbox:

```
import { useField } from "formik";

const CheckboxWithoutMUI = ({ label, ...rest }) => {
  const [field, meta] = useField({ ...rest, type: "checkbox" });
  const { value, ...fieldExceptValue } = field;
  return (
    <div>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" {...fieldExceptValue} {...rest} />
        {label}
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CheckboxWithoutMUI;
```

[image: Edit blissful-thompson-soj2uk]

If you change the syntax of the MUI Checkbox to be more similar to your non-MUI version (pass all of the `field` props to it), it works as desired:

```
import { useField } from "formik";
import FormControlLabel from "@mui/material/FormControlLabel";
import Checkbox from "@mui/material/Checkbox";

interface IProps {
  label: string;
  name: string;
}

const CheckboxField = ({ label, ...rest }: IProps) => {
  const [field] = useField({ ...rest, type: "checkbox" });
  return (
    <div>
      <FormControlLabel label={label} control={<Checkbox {...field} />} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default CheckboxField;
```

[image: Edit frosty-newton-n9h5pd]

It is also sufficient to just add `value` to what you already had:

```
import { useField } from "formik";
import FormControlLabel from "@mui/material/FormControlLabel";
import Checkbox from "@mui/material/Checkbox";

interface IProps {
  label: string;
  name: string;
}

const CheckboxField = ({ label, ...rest }: IProps) => {
  const [field] = useField({ ...rest, type: "checkbox" });

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControlLabel
        label={label}
        control={
          <Checkbox
            checked={field.checked}
            onChange={field.onChange}
            id={field.name}
            value={field.value}
          />
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default CheckboxField;
```

[image: Edit weathered-silence-e5lo60]

Comment: Good lord. Let me just say how much I loathe HTML checkboxes. (-; So `value` needs to be the same as `checked` in the case where we don't need anything other than on/off, but then it can be different if you want to, I guess, group checkboxes? I don't think I've ever (knowingly) used the `value` prop before.

Anyway, thanks so much for the detailed response, and showing me my silly mistake.